# Estimating a set of probabilities for sequences of independent events.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, systems-of-equations

Assume a line of obstacles, if dropping a marble at obstacle position $n$ it should stop with (as close to a given probability $p(n)$ as possible) somewhere before obstacle $n+m(n)$. Assuming we have $m(n)$ and $p(n)$ sampled at least some values of $n$. How can we estimate the independent probabilities of stopping (or passing) of each individual obstacle?

Let us assume the event of passing a given obstacle is independent of having passed any previous or passing any subsequent obstacles, but that they are always encountered in the same order: $$1\to 2\to 3 \to \cdots \to N$$

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What does it mean to "drop a marble"?  And your verb tenses...If I drop a marble at $n$ it "should have stopped" before $n+m(n)$.  That refers to something that happened prior to your dropping it?  The probabilities involved are always exactly $.5$?  Or is $m(n)$ defined to be the least distance such that the probability exceeds $.5$?  Anyway, I think you need to add more information.

Comment: Ok trying to make it clearer, also more general. $50\%$ exchanged for $p(n)$

Comment: Ok, so you start the marble at $n$...so it encounters obstacle $n$?  (that's just a bookkeeping point).  So, let $\psi(n)$ be the probability of clearing obstacle $i$.  (so $p(n)=\prod (1-\psi(n+i))$).  Have we got any prior on the $\psi(n)$?  each sampling gives us information about a product of them and we get a lot of information out of overlaps, but it seems hard to say much in general.

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical method?  Absent some kind of prior, I'd assume $\psi(n)$ was constant on each overlap...I haven't thought it through but maybe it's always possible to solve for that. Certainly it is often possible. Then you could look to smooth the results over the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way that works. Following the ideas in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178166/a-logarithmic-probabilistic-version-of-integration?noredirect=1#comment4480569_2178166), we approximate the integrals with riemann sums (although we already have a discrete case with explicit product/sums). All $m(n)$ are 2 and the probabilities $p(n)$ given by the vector $\bf d$:

$${\bf v} = 2^\left[\min_{\bf v}\left\{\|{\bf Tv} - \log_2({\bf d})\|_2^2\right\}\right]$$

$${\bf T} = \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1
\end{array}\right], \log_2({\bf d}) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}-1\\-2\\-3\\-4\\-5\\-6\end{array}\right]$$

So $$\cases{{v_1}^1\cdot {v_2}^1 = 2^{-1/2}\\{v_3}^1\cdot {v_4}^1 = 2^{-1}\\\vdots}$$

With a small isotropic *Tikhonov regularizer* with $\lambda = 10^{-6}$ gives us the solution:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
0.840896488111804\\
0.840896488111804\\
0.707106903718765\\
0.707106903718765\\
0.594603712056721\\
0.594603712056721\\
0.500000173286739\\
0.500000173286739\\
0.420448389772112\\
0.420448389772112\\
0.353553574391631\\
0.353553574391631
\end{array}\right]$$

I we plug back in, we see several well known facts, for example $\sqrt{1/2} = 0.7071069\cdots, \sqrt{1/4} = 0.5$.

So we can build linear least squares problems encoding exponents instead of coefficients as numbers. As the system is underdetermined we happen to get the solution where pairs are equal, but bear in mind many other constraints can be put. Simultaneous overlapping constraints could probably be useful in some application..?