# Markov Ageing Chain Example

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am having trouble solving a homework question and I hope you guys can help me out, the question is:

> David shaves in the morning on the days he decides to shave. (He does not shave
>   everyday.) The time between two consecutive shaving days can be 1, 2, 3, and
>   4 days, in probabilities $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{8}$, and $\frac{1}{24}$ respectively. After each shaving,
>   David decides the date of the next shaving independent of previous shaving days.
>   Use an ageing chain to model David's shaving habit.

My thinking was that the probabilities to model his shaving habits would be

$p(k+1,k)=\frac{1}{2}$, $p(k+2,k)=\frac{1}{3}$ etc.

Yet I do not think this is completly correct.

Comment: Finally an example where my answer to this question can be used:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175751/estimating-a-set-of-probabilities-for-sequences-of-independent-events

Comment: "My thinking was that the probabilities to model his shaving habits would be $p(k+1,k)=\frac{1}{2}$, $p(k+2,k)=\frac{1}{3}$ etc." I fail to understand what you are trying to say here. If the desired Markov chain describes the *age*, that is, the time since the last shave occurred, then the state space is $\{0,1,2,3\}$, right? Which transitions on this state space are you suggesting, precisely?

Comment: What information exactly are you trying to infer? What proportion of days David shaves in the long run?

Comment: I get that with probability $24/65$ David shaves today, with the same probability, he'll shave tomorrow; with probability $12/65$ he'll shave in two days, while the probabilities that he'll shave in three or four days are $4/65$ and $1/65$, respectively.  Is this the kind of result you're looking for?

Comment: See # 24 at https://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/491-2/HO/491-Review-2.pdf    In your case $p_1=1/2$, $p_2=1/3$ and $p_3=1/4$.